# Mock a decorated Stream using PowerMockito

Tags: io, inputstream, powermock, outputstream, word-wrap

So I have a class which takes an OutputStream in the constructor and creates a PrintWriter from it inside a method. Question is how do I get this PrintWriter to verify it?

```
Example public Class(OutputStream output) {}
public void foo() {
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);
}
```

What I try to do is:

```
PrintWriter writer = PowerMockito.mock(PrintWriter.class)
PowerMockito
    .whenNew(PrintWriter.class)
    .withArguments(output)
    .thenReturn(writer);
```

However I get that there are no interractions with this writer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you provided full code snippet with PowerMock configuration. Then I could help you and give advise, now I may only guess what could be wrong, but I'm trying:

The `PrintWriter`has several constructors which could accept `OutputStream`and PowerMock have a defect that it could incorrect guess which constructor is mocked, when you pass only arguments when a class had overloaded constructors.

Also it could be common mistake, you haven't added the class which create an instance of `PrintWriter` to `@PrepareForTest`.

So, worked example in base on my assumption case:

```
public class PrintWriterCreator {

    private final PrintWriter printWriter;

    public PrintWriterCreator(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
    }

    public void write(String message){
        printWriter.write(message);
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({PrintWriter.class, PrintWriterCreator.class})
public class PrintWriterCreatorTest {


    @Mock
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    @Mock
    private PrintWriter printWriterMock;

    private PrintWriterCreator printWriterCreator;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        whenNew(PrintWriter.class).withParameterTypes(OutputStream.class).withArguments(eq(outputStream)).thenReturn
                                                                                                       (printWriterMock);

        printWriterCreator = new PrintWriterCreator(outputStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void testWrite() throws Exception {
        String message = "someMessage";
        printWriterCreator.write(message);

        verifyNew(PrintWriter.class).withArguments(outputStream);

        verify(printWriterMock).write(eq(message));
    }


}
```